# How can I get an outlined comment icon from Google Material Design Library?

Tags: css, material-design, angularjs-material, google-fonts

[They say](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=outline) both filled and outlined comment is `comment` yet when I try `<md-icon>comment</md-icon>` that's a filled one. How can I get an outlined one with using `md-icon`?

I tried `<md-icon>comment_outlined</md-icon>` but it didn't work so far.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no support for Outlined icons via Google Fonts. In fact, the icons listed on the website are in fact `data` URIs!

See this (outstanding) [issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/773) for more info.

Comment: Does Google Fonts mean <md-icon> tag here?

Comment: @AlexKornakov I'm sorry? Could you clarify what you mean?